# Ubuntu 14.04 blank desktop after login

Tags: 14.04, login

I know this question has already been asked so many times . I have followed everything as suggested in similar question asked here. Like reinstall ubuntu desktop , unity etc . But none of them worked .  This problem started when I accidentally move some file to `/home/user` folder  here `user` is my username . While moving my pc got hanged . Then I reset and the problem begin .Each time I login I can only see blank screen only with a mouse pointer .   How can I solve it ?

**Edit**

I can log into guest session

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: Tried it , but didn't work